# Group objects with the same ids from two different JSON files

Tags: python, json

I have two json files with multiples `objectID`. I use them to calculate an average value of each object with the same ID. I thought I had found a way with this code:

```
def formatAvg():
    for itemcla in dataClassified:
        objectIdClassified = itemcla["objectID"]

        for itemauction in dataAuctions:
            objectIdAuctions = itemauction["objectID"]

            if objectIdClassified == objectIdAuctions:
                itemauction["avg_total"] = {}
...
formatAvg()
```

Where `dataClassified` and `dataAuctions` are lists and where `itemcla` and `itemauction` are objects with the same objectID. But it doesn't work at all. I think it's because the `if objectIdClassified == objectIdAuctions:` line just checks objectID but doesn't group them.

A sample of the dataClassified JSON:

```
[{
    "objectID": 10000,
    "cars_getroute": "url",
    "car_value": 50000
},
{
    "objectID": 10001,
    "cars_getroute": "url",
    "car_value": 10000
},
{
    "objectID": 10003,
    "cars_getroute": "url",
    "car_value": 50000
}]
```

Sample of the dataAuctions JSON:

```
[{
    "objectID": 10000,
    "value": 52000
},
{
    "objectID": 10001,
    "value": 12000
},
{
    "objectID": 10002,
    "value": 54000
}]
```

As you can see, the order is not always respected. I don't have any output because there isn't any change.

My expected output:

```
[{
        "objectID": 10000,
        "value": 52000,
        "total_avg": 52000
    },
    {
        "objectID": 10001,
        "value": 12000,
        "total_avg": 11000
        }
    },
    {
        "objectID": 10002,
        "value": 54000,
        "total_avg": 54000
    }]
```

Comment: Please provide a small (minimal) JSON sample and think about adding logs / outputs instead of thinking, guessing is not a bad thing but often leads to wasting a lot of time if what you suppose is in incorrect. Logging will just show what is going on and will generally lead to the solution for trivial cases.

Comment: also, _O(N^2)_!

Comment: First, group the items in dataAuctions into a hash mapping their id to a collection of matching itemauction. Then, for each collection you can calculate the average. If you try to do this in a single doubly-nested loop you'll actually have to make two passes in the inner loop.

Comment: Christophe, I added samples of my JSON to help, thank you for your answer

Comment: @lf_celine - a sample of what you are expecting to see would help people help you. Also, does `dataClassified` really alternate between 'car_number' and 'car_value'?

Comment: No, it was an error, I updated my question

Answer (score 1):

Converting to a dict makes it much simpler and faster:

```
def formatAvg(dataAuctions, dataClassified):
    da = {i["objectID"]: i["value"] for i in dataAuctions}
    dc = {i["objectID"]: {"cars_getroute": i["cars_getroute"], "car_value": i["car_value"]} for i in dataClassified}

    # First pass iterated on wrong list...
    #return [{"objectID": k, "value": v, "total_avg": round((da[k]+k)/2) if k in da else k} for k,v in dc.items()]
    return [{"objectID": k, "value": v, "total_avg": round((v+dc[k]['car_value'])/2) if k in dc else v} for k,v in da.items()]
```